# Improving XSL translation using Apache XalanC++ libaray

Tags: c++, c, xalan

**Function converter() accepts parsed xsl stream as input and returns the output string.
Can I improve this function ?
Can I cache incoming strings ?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.**

> ```
>  int  converter( char *xslInput,char *htmlOutput)
>    {
>     int theResult=-1;
>     int i=0;
>     char c;
>     char xmlbuf[100] = {'\0'};
>     char xmlbuf1[]="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"";
>     char xmlbuf2[]="\"?><a></a>";
>     char default_encoding[]="iso-8859-1";
>     char final_encoding[15];
>     char *encoding = NULL;
> ```

```
    strcpy(final_encoding,default_encoding);
    strcpy(xmlbuf,xmlbuf1);
    strcat(xmlbuf,final_encoding);
    strcat(xmlbuf,xmlbuf2);

    XALAN_USING_STD(cerr)
    XALAN_USING_STD(cout)
    XALAN_USING_STD(endl)
    XALAN_USING_STD(ofstream)
    XALAN_USING_STD(ostrstream)
    XALAN_USING_STD(istrstream)

    XALAN_USING_STD(ostrstream)

    XALAN_USING_XERCES(XMLPlatformUtils)
    XALAN_USING_XALAN(XalanTransformer)

    ostrstream      theOutput;

    // 2. Initialize Xerces and Xalan
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    XalanTransformer::initialize();

    {
            // 3. Create a XalanTransformer
            XalanTransformer theXalanTransformer;

            // Our input streams...
            istrstream      theXMLStream(xmlbuf, strlen(xmlbuf));
            istrstream      theXSLStream(xslInput, strlen(xslInput));
            ostrstream      theOutput;

            // 4. Prepare the input and output sources
            XALAN_USING_XALAN(XSLTInputSource)
            XALAN_USING_XALAN(XSLTResultTarget)
           // 5. Perform the transformation
            theResult = theXalanTransformer.transform(&theXMLStream, &theXSLStream, theOutput);
            if(theResult != 0)
            {
                    cerr << "StreamTransform Error: \n" << theXalanTransformer.getLastError()
                     << endl
                     << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    theOutput << '\0';
                    strcpy(htmlOutput, theOutput.str());
                    cout << "Result of Transformation is SUCCESS\n" ;

            }

    }

            // 5. Shutdown the transformation thingy...
            XalanTransformer::terminate();
            XalanTransformer::ICUCleanUp();
            XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

    return theResult;
    }
```

Comment: For example, why do you need final_encoding anyway?

Comment: Wait... does this code even work? I'm asking about the call to transform(). It passes the **ostrstream** to handle the output, but according to the API the expected parameter is an **XSLTResultTarget** object.

Comment: Also, I am fairly sure the third parameter to transform() should have the '&' operator as well:
`theXalanTransformer.transform(&theXMLStream, &theXSLStream, &theOutput);`

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that too much local variables are used,e.g., char xmlbuf1, char xmlbuf2, etc. Furthermore, can you use std::string instead of those raw c-style arrays?